# What is the most suitable "light up" or "discover"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Should I use "discovered" rather than "lit up"?

*We **lit up** that most of user's actions on Social Media such as FB, ..., induce a boost of dopamine level.*

Comment: Where does “to light up” come from? To me that means smoking . . . something.

Answer (score 1):

I want to avoid "discover", *"brought to light"* seems to be more suitable.

*We **brought to light** that most of user's actions on Social Media such as FB, ..., induce a boost of dopamine level.*

Comment: If you just want to avoid "discover", you can use "find", "determine", or "observe".